# Ruby + Mac + File System Operations + Aliases

Tags: ruby, macos, file, system, alias

A) Does Ruby have a good way to access Mac's file system? Specifically, check for folder names, file names, move files and directories around...

I've been searching for 20 minutes and the only thing I can find is FileUtils, and I can't find ANY documentation or websites about it.

B) If the above is possible, can you use that same system to create an alias or symbolic link to a file or folder?

Comment: you read this [FileUtils](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html) ? there is everything you need.

Comment: JUST found the proper documentation about two minutes ago. However, still don't know how to make an alias?

Comment: I have posted the link to the documentation as well as instructions on how to create symlinks as a response to your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678630/ruby-fileutils-alias-on-mac Why are you asking it again? Closing this one, since the other question is better formulated...