# Ruby FileUtils alias on Mac?

Tags: ruby, macos, hyperlink, fileutils

How do I use Ruby's fileutils to make an alias on Mac's filesystem? Symbolic link would work too, either one. Or would I need to use some sort of shell script to do so?

Comment: No.. I am not getting you.. Could you be more specific ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`FileUtils::symlink`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-symlink):

```
FileUtils.symlink(src, dest)
```

To learn how to make an alias via AppleScript, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51709/can-i-create-a-desktop-shortcut-alias-to-a-folder-from-the-terminal

As a side note: except for the aliases (via AppleScript), Ruby will handle this correctly on any supported file system.